# Which is the correct formula for calculating percent variation?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am creating a data analysis model, and I would like to know what the variation of a given month in 2019 versus the same month in 2018 is.

For example:
Jun 2019: 358.269
Jun 2018: 423.149

I would like to know which of the two formulas below would be correct in this case, for me to obtain the percentage variation:

Formula 1:

```
(358.269 / 423.149 - 1 ) * 100 = -15.33%
```

Formula 2:

```
((358.269 - 423.149) / 358.269) * 100 = -18.10%
```

I'm doing this analysis using pandas

```
df['variation'] = ((df['2019'] / df['2018'] - 1) * 100 ).round(2)
df['variation'] = ((df['2019'] - df['2018']) / df['2019']) * 100).round(2)
```

I would like to know which of the two formulas is correct, or if there is another formula, I would like to know what it is for me to correct in my code.

Comment: I believe that usually, you get the older value as the denominator. So 2019 - 2018 / 2018 * 100

Comment: It would be more informative to write the formulae as `((x - y) / y) * 100` and `((x - y) / x) * 100` instead of writing the first one as `(x / y - 1) * 100`. That being said, @IWHKYB is right in every case that I have ever seen in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question suggests, the percent variation between two numbers depends on which number you start with as a baseline. This is generally expressed through context.

Something like "The stocks went up by 18% last month" means that 18% of the starting amount was added on: `(end - start) / start = 0.18`.

On the other hand, a formulation like "This phone was 30% more expensive last year" is the opposite: `(start - end) / end = 0.3`.

For your particular case, decide which month provides the reference. "a given month in 2019 versus the same month in 2018" *sounds* like you want to know how much more/less the 2019value  is relative to what you had in 2018, so you would use `(value_2019 - value_2018) / value_2018`.

Placing the 2019 value in the denominator tells you how much less 2018 was relavive to 2019. In general, we set our baseline as the first datum chronologically, so you very rarely see this reversed formulation.

Either formula can be rewritten to factor out the denominator: `value_2019 / value_2018 - 1` or `1 - value_2018 / value_2019`.

**TL;DR**

Use `(value_2019 - value_2018) / value_2018` or the equivalent `value_2019 / value_2018 - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Year over Year change or variation as you say have these two formula

I prefer first one

```
year_over_year_change = ((this_year - last_year) /(last_year))*100
```

```
df['variation'] = ((df['2019']- df['2018'])/df['2018'])*100
```

second solution

```
year_over_year_change ((this_year /last_year) -1)*100
```

```
df['variation'] = ((df['2019']/df['2018'])-1)*100
```